# How to change Django datetime field format in datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, datepicker

I have a model field called `close_date`

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    close_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

In my forms, I don't do add any classes to display this because I will do it in my template using django-widget-tweaks. However, my forms look like this:

forms.py

```
class NewProjectForm (ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['close_date', ...]
```

templates

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
    <div class="form-group" id="close_date">
        <label>{{project_form.close_date.label}}</label>
        <div class="input-group date">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
            {% render_field project_form.close_date class="form-control" type="text" %}
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
        $('#close_date .input-group.date').datepicker({
            todayBtn: "linked",
            keyboardNavigation: false,
            forceParse: false,
            calendarWeeks: true,
            autoclose: true
        });
</script>
```

All this works fine, I can display the form, save it to the database and even display data to the user, but when I want to edit the this object and I populate the form from my views, I see this in the datepicker input field:

```
2018-02-28 00:00:00
```

How can I change what is displayed there from `2018-02-28 00:00:00` to `02/28/2018`?

Is that on the django side of things or the JS side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried specifying the input format in your form, like so?

```
close_date = DateField(input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y'], label=_('Installation Date'),widget=DateInput())
```

Comment: This works! Does exactly what I wanted to do! Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `DateField`([doc link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField)) instead of a `DateTimeField` inside your model :)

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a partial solution as it is 3 am in the morning (sorry). Use a `DateField` instead of a `DateTimeField` so that the `00:00:00` part is not there anymore.

Next, you need to reformat the date from `2018-02-28` to `02/28/2018`. That's it. From what I understand, either input will work with the form, but during editing the one with the `-` is preferred by Django so that's what it shows you.

If this bothers you then either use a JS library to put a calendar so that users use a calendar to input/change the data rather than type it by hand, or use a custom javascript code to change the input after the whole page loads.

Comment: I appreciate you answering my question so late at night, but, there is already a calendar widget that I am using in my template, when they click on the `close_date` input box, a datepicker widget will pop up and let them choose the date. I wanted to know the if the format in which it is currently displayed can be changed

Comment: Well, the solution I gave you is the `hacky` way to solve this problem. Create a JS script that will apply to the date field every time it is changed. Then just readjust the text in your preferred format. Please Google a bit for how to write the code. If you have a specific question regarding the code I can help you. You will learn so much more if you try to code yourself!